# How do I share data between 2 FreeBSD kernel modules?

Tags: kernel, freebsd, kernel-module

I have multiple kernel modules in my embedded device that do things like handle the LCD, the touchscreen, the serial ports etc.

One kernel module is able to read the PCB version.

I would like for my LCD module to be able to read the PCB version as well.  The easiest way to do this would be to load the PCB version module first, and have the LCD module ask it for the version.

Both modules are loadable .ko's, and both are written by me.

Is there an easy way to:

1. make a function call from one module to another?
2. read a global variable in another module?
3. make an ioctl call from a module to another module?

My preference is #3.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

To call a function in another module:

1. place the MODULE_DEPEND macro at the top of the local module to a) make sure that the other module is loaded first, and b) that you are able to link against it's functions.  Not sure about b.  E.g.:

   MODULE_DEPEND(lcd_mod, timer_mod, 1, 1, 1);
2. Place a declaration for the remote function in the local module.
3. simply call the remote function.